# 500 internal error when setting up reverse proxy for Wikipedia

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, 500-error

Access to Wikipedia can be disturbed randomly in my country
Running Debian 7 with nginx 1.2.1 with additional `ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module`

use several sub-domains to reverse proxy corresponding sub-domain of wikipedia 
`w.mydomain.tld` for `zh.wikipedia.org`
`m.w.mydomain.tld` for `zh.m.wikipedia.org`.  For mobile site
`up.w.mydomain.tld` for `upload.wikimedia.org`

My nginx config looks like this

```
    .......
    location / {
    proxy_pass https://zh.wikipedia.org;
    proxy_cookie_domain zh.wikipedia.org w.mydomain.tld;
    proxy_redirect https://zh.wikipedia.org/ /;
    proxy_redirect https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/ https://m.w.mymain.tld/;
    proxy_set_header Host "zh.wikipedia.org";
    proxy_set_header Referer "https://zh.wikipedia.org$request_uri";
    subs_filter_types text/css text/xml text/javascript;
    subs_filter zh.wikipedia.org w.mydomain.tld;
    subs_filter upload.wikimedia.org up.w.mydomain.tld;
    subs_filter zh.m.wikipedia.org m.w.mydomain.tld;
    sub_filter_once off;
    }
            location https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/{
            rewrite ^/(.*) https://m.w.mydomain.tld/$1 permanent;
            }
    }
```

Server config for m.w.domain.tld and up.w.domain.tld are similar

No matter how I always get a 500 internal server error and there are no infos on `error.log`

Many thanks in advance:)

Update: I have tried remove the last location section and a similar configuration works for Google, still no clue:(

Comment: `location` does not allow a `http(s)://` value.

Comment: What do you server logs say ?

Comment: I have tried define upstream in http block and use it in location block, doesn't work,either

Comment: Have also tried remove `location https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/{ rewrite ^/(.*) https://m.w.mydomain.tld/$1 permanent; }` section, still get a 500 error